# Octave - comparing vectors (element by element)

Tags: vector, octave

how do I compare 2 vectors of equal length - I want to get number of elements (which have the same position in both vectors) that differ.

```
Example:
x=[1 0 0 1 1]
y=[1 0 1 1 0]
result should be 2 since 3rd and 5th element of both vectors differ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

`x==y` will return a vector of length `length(x)` (or `length(y)` since `x` and `y` are the same length) with `1` where `x(i)==y(i)` and `0` where `x(i)~=y(i)`:

```
>> x==y
ans =

   1   1   0   1   0
```

So all you need to do is sum the elements of `x==y` and subtract that to `length(x)`

```
>> length(x)-sum(x==y)
ans =  2
```

Arnaud

Comment: To avoid problems in the case of a matrix, I'd suggest to replace `length` and `sum` with `numel` and `nnz`. I specially don't like `length` since it's has the weird definition of length of the largest dimension.

Comment: Good point, although the OP did specify `x` and `y` to be vectors, not matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Compare two matrices (/vectors) with -

```
z = eq(x, y) % returns 1 for match and 0 for mismatch
```

which returns a matrix `z` of 0s and 1s. Finally count the number of zeros in it:

```
sum(z == 0); % find total non matching elements
```

Answer (score 0):

sum(ne(x, y)) % find all elements that are different
gives 2